How to access the camera and microphone from within a Webview in unity3d android?
How to access the camera from within a Webview in unity3d android?
Im using Uniwebview. the camera on my unity editor is working after camera permission was enabled BUT NOT on my android device. Camera is not opening when i enabled the camera permission on my android build

Did you https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.RequestUserAuthorization.html ?
